# Clear Glide Image Cache in Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am using glide library for showing images. I am trying to clear glide cache by using the following code:

```
Glide.get(MainActivity.this).clearDiskCache();
Glide.get(MainActivity.this).clearMemory();
```

the above code is inside Async and I call in Do background part.

When I run this I am always getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread
at com.bumptech.glide.util.Util.assertMainThread(Util.java:135)
at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.clearMemory(Glide.java:370)
```

What could be wrong here? If I use the above in MainThread it is asking to run it in background.

How do I clear cache?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try executing `Glide.get(MainActivity.this).clearMemory();` in `onPostExecute()` ?

Comment: Nope. I will try it.

Comment: @MuchOverflow: That was the issue. Sorry my bad! Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`clearMemory()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#clearMemory()) must be called on the main thread.
[`clearDiskCache()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#clearDiskCache()) must be called on a background thread.

You can't call both at once on the same thread.