# Glide loads the old image

Tags: android, file, android-glide

I have a problem that each time , I take a photo and and I try to display it. Glide load me the old file. I check the file locally , it has been changed successfully.  But the old image is displayed.

This is my code :

```
  public void onCameraCaptureCompleted(final File photoFile) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopCamera();
                pickedImg.setImageBitmap(null);
                Glide.with(TakePhotoFragment.this)
                        .load(photoFile)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .dontAnimate()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .into(pickedImg);
            }
        });

    }
```

Who knows how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with [**`skipMemoryCache`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html#skipMemoryCache-boolean-)

> Allows the loaded resource to skip the memory cache.

```
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
```

**NOTE**

If same problem still coming then use [**`clearMemory()`**](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#clearMemory()).
For good approach, Create Application Class and add this

```
public class RootApplication extends Application 
{
   @Override public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    Glide.get(this).clearMemory();
}
```

Make sure, added this **Application** class in `Manifest`.

```
<application
    android:name=".RootApplication"
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to clear the cache stored and then restart the application manually

or

just clear the cache from code only. just call `clearMemory()` on glide.

Have a look here for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168383/clear-glide-image-cache-in-android)

[Docs](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#clearMemory())

Answer (score 0):

```
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
```

just this worked for me.